# C++ ADO Connection Pooling

Tags: c++, sql, database, sybase, connection-pooling

Previously, I had my own custom ConnectionPool class,,, but I found out that I can instead use the connection pooling feature simply by including it in my Connection string..
(http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17768/ADO-NET-Connection-Pooling-at-a-Glance)

So here is my simple test code so far:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    ::CoInitiazlie();

    char* ConnString = "Provider=ASEOLEDB; Data Source=xxx;  Min Pool Size=5;";

    _ConnectionPtr MyPointer = NULL;
    MyPointer.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Connection));
    MyPointer -> Open(ConnString, "myusername", "mypassword", adConnectUnspecified);

    //BREAK POINT....

    MyPointer -> Close();    

    ::CoUninitialize();

}
```

So according to the description from the link,, this should have opened and kept 5 connections inside the pool at BREAK POINT.. (due to the "Min Pool Size=5" Option inside the Connection String).

However, when I open up the session manager, only I see only 1 connection opened..

I am not sure what I did wrong.. How exactly does setting Min Pool Size in the Connection string create a connection pool??

Thanks

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, it is the floor of the connection pool size once it has been *met*; not on inception. Did you try ramping it to a dozen or so connections, then backing them off *below* 5 and determining the results held in-pool? And are you looking at authenticated *active* connections by mistake?

Comment: @WhozCraig Actually I'm not sure how to open dozen or so connections.. Should I create multiple "_ConnectionPtr"s ? Or should I call multiple "->Open()"s from the same pointer..? Sorry I'm a little confused about  how Connection Pooling works..

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc20063.0600/html/easperf/CHDCGCEJ.htm) seems to indicate that connections are created as needed, but `Min Pool Size` dictates the *minimum* number that will be kept after pruning:

> **Minimum Pool Size (minPoolSize):**
>
> The minimum number of connections in the pool. When open connections are idle, the pool is pruned to this size. The default is zero.
>
> If no minimum size is specified, EAServer opens connections as-needed to fill the pool up to the maximum size.

Maybe you want to set `Initial Pool Size` as well:

> **Initial Pool Size (initialPoolSize)**
>
> The initial number of pooled connections, allocated at server start-up. If not set, the default is 0.

Comment: Thanks. I tried "Provider=ASEOLEDB; Data Source=xxx; initialPoolSize=5;", but still shows only 1 open connection..

Comment: Looks like you have mixed spacing.  Try either `initialPoolSize` (no space) or `Initial Pool Size` (two spaces).

Comment: Also it's not clear if _an actual connection is made_ when the pool is created or if the connection is not made until a request actually occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried both spacings but nothing changed.. Also, I've actually tried executing a query after opening the connection, but didn't do anything

Comment: By "didn't do anything" you mean it didn't create 5 connections, only 1?

Comment: By the way, the link you refer to is about ADO.NET connection poling - you are using Sybase's connection pooling.